# Unable to write file to android root

Tags: android, root

I'm just figuring out to write an app to access superuser access and understand it's working.

So I'm writing some text to file using the following method:

```
public void update(View v){
    Process p;
    try{
        // Preform su to get root privledges
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        // Attempt to write a file to a root-only
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/etc/temporary.txt\n");

        // Close the terminal
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        try{
            p.waitFor();
            if(p.exitValue() != 225){
                showToast("ROOTED !");
            } else {
                showToast("not root");
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            showToast("not root");
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        showToast("not root");
    }
}
```

So a toast `ROOTED !` is being shown when I call this method. Means the file `temporary.txt` must be created inside `/system/etc` folder of my phone. But when I browse to that folder using Root Explorer app then I see nothing there.
This thing is confusing me because the `ROOTED !` toast is shown but I can't see the file.

And yeah my phone is rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System` is mounted `ro`, if you want to try to write something inside `system/etc` you should first remount it `rw` .

Edit:

from the mount documentation

> All files accessible in a Unix system are arranged in one big tree,
>   the file hierarchy, rooted at /. These files can be spread out over
>   several devices. The mount command serves to attach the filesystem
>   found on some device to the big file tree.

That`s the output on my device:

```
shell@android:/ $ mount                                                        
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
```

as you can see `/` is mounted as read-only

Comment: It worked. but can you explain a little bit more ??  I'm still getting confused as I'm not good with Linux.